# Pass raw pointer to function that accepts unique_ptr as parameter

Tags: c++, templates, smart-pointers

I'm trying to write a function that accepts unique_ptr to classes derived from `Base` as a parameters (to indicate ownership transfer). I've come up with the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

class Base
{
  public:
    Base() {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
    Derived() {}
};


void foo(std::unique_ptr<Derived> _data) {}

template <class T>
void boo(std::unique_ptr<T> _data) {
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<T*, Base*>::value,
                  "Only classes derived from Base can be used as "
                  "parameter for boo");
}


int main() { foo(new Derived); }
```

But when I try to compile it, I get an error telling me that `could not convert ‘(operator new(1ul), (<statement>, ((Derived*)<anonymous>)))’ from ‘Derived*’ to ‘std::unique_ptr<Derived>’` if I use `foo` and the same (plus some template details) when I use `boo`. If I understood everything correctly, what I'm being told is that there is no constructor for `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` that could accept pointer for `Derived`. But when I looked on cppreference [page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) for unqiue_ptr constructor, I saw that there is such constructor (number 3-4).

The question is: How can I make a function that accepts `unique_ptr` as parameter and call it with raw pointer.

**P.S.** I'm trying to write a function that accepts `unique_ptr` because I want to indicate that ownership of the parameter will be transferred. If you know how to write a function with a signature that could clearly and unambiguously show that ownership is being transferred, I would also accept this as an answer. This function can either template with `static_assert` or with `Base` pointer as a parameter.

**P.S.** The main problem is how to make `foo(new Derived)`. I know that I can use  `boo(std::make_unique<Derived>())` (in that case everything works) but I also *really* want to know why the example with raw pointer does not work, because I don't know how to indicate that I'm "stealing" ownership for raw pointer.

**P.S** Example of usage (with raw pointers) (**DOES NOT WORK**)

```
Derived* derived_1 = new Derived;
// Do something with derived_1
boo(derived_1); // Pass to function and don't worry about `delete`
                // because you know that ownership has been
                // transferred and no longer is your concern
```

And with smart pointers

```
void foo_2(std::unique_ptr<Derived>& _data) {
     boo(std::move(_data)); 
}

std::unique_ptr<Derived> derived_2 = std::make_unique<Derived>();
// Do something with derived_2
foo(std::move(derived_2)); // Have to use `std::move`
                           // or
foo_2(derived_2);
```

Second one (omitting need for new function) is not as simple as first one (even though I should admit that the difference is not so big (maybe 2x typing))

Comment: why not `foo(std::make_unique<Derived>())`?

Comment: What is wrong with `int main() { foo(std::make_unique<Derived>()); }`?

Comment: @Ron I know. But to call them I have to have unique_ptr. If I pass unique_ptr as parameter calling `data()/releatse()` is pointless because ownership has already been transferred. If I pass raw pointer -> I get compile errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overloads 3 and 4 do not apply here.  Their signature is

```
unique_ptr( pointer p, /* see below */ d1 ) noexcept;

unique_ptr( pointer p, /* see below */ d2 ) noexcept;
```

and they take a second parameter that is a custom deleter.  The only overload that applies is 2 which is

```
explicit unique_ptr( pointer p ) noexcept;
```

Since it is marked as explicit it will not implicitly convert the pointer to a `unique_ptr`.  This is a safety issues and it is correct to make it explicit.  If it was not `explicit` then

```
void foo(std::unique_ptr<int> _data) {}

int main()
{
    int bar;
    foo(&bar);
}
```

would compile but it would be undefined behavior as `_data` would try to delete the pointer when it was destroyed at the end of `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be **explicit** in your conversion:

```
int main()
{
    Derived* d = nullptr;
    BadInterface(&d); // mainly d = new Derived(..);
    foo(std::unique_ptr<Derived>(d));
}
```

which gives in your one liner case:

```
foo(std::unique_ptr<Derived>(new Derived));
```